# How do booklice avoid dessication?

Tags: entomology, physiology, death

I often find booklice (aka [psocids](http://entoplp.okstate.edu/profiles/go/psocid/facts.html)) in old paper notes I have in semi-storage. These pages of paper are intentionally left in dry conditions on my desk to avoid damage. However, if the psocids live and feed totally within these pages, how are they getting any water? **How do the booklice avoid drying out and dying?**